# matplotlib imshow() using 3xN RGB array

Tags: python, numpy

I use custom 3xN data with value range (0, 1) as RGB color, and want to use matplotlib.imshow() to show it.

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

Z = np.vstack([np.zeros((1, 256)), np.zeros((1, 256,)), np.zeros((1, 256,))])
im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='none', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

I expect this to give me a black image. But instead I get a green one like this:
[image]

And the Y-ticks look funny. I don't understand the -0.5 tick on the Y-axis at all. Why does the y-axis range between [-0.5, 2.5]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody landing on this page several years out, OP figured out the reasons for  the initial issue but the easier fix is: `np.dstack()`. [numpy.dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Z = np.vstack([np.zeros((1, 256)), np.zeros((1, 256,)), np.zeros((1, 256,))])
im = plt.imshow(np.dstack(Z), interpolation='none', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the better solution. This should be the new accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out myself:

1. imshow() expect the input data array size to be 1 x N x 3. 3 refers to RGB.
2. Because my data was 3 x N, imshow() considered it three data, hence the [-0.5, 2.5] simply reflects three vertically-stacked data rows, each spanning a 0~1.0 range.

Here is a simple fix:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np

Z = np.vstack([np.zeros((1, 256)), np.zeros((1, 256,)), np.zeros((1, 256,))]).transpose()
Z = Z[None, ...]
im = plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='none', aspect='auto')
plt.colorbar(im, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Lol, sorry, we must have started editing about the same time! Thank you anyways! +1 to you too!

Answer (score 1):

Because you've basically sent an invalid image to `np.imshow`. Try to open an image from your computer and compare. Opening an image will give you a `(dimx, dimy, color_depth)` shape, while your `Z` is of `(3, 256)` shape. To see exactly what happens you should probably check out `imshow` source, but I'm fairly sure they've some error handling that produces your result. To create an image you should probably do

```
img = np.zeros((800, 500, 3), dtype=np.float32)
```

which will give you a black square like you desire.

Additionally, imshow shows a coordinate system which has a `(0,0` in the upper left corner to match how everyone else displays image coordinate systems traditionally.